# C++ class name does not name a type

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#include "Setup.h"
#include "mainCharacter.h"

class Main {

public:
    Main(int pScreenWidth, int pScreenHeight);
    ~Main();

void gameLoop();

private:
    bool quit;
    Setup* setup;

    mainCharacter* tom;

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;

    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
};
#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

I saw the other topics on this, but the error im getting is not of the same type, how can it tell me that

```
Setup* setup;
mainCharacter* tom;
```

does not name a type when the includes are above ?
im using code::blocks if that matters.

EDIT://////////////////////

This is the Setup header:

```
#ifndef SETUP_H_INCLUDED
#define SETUP_H_INCLUDED

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>

#include "Main.h"
#include "Sprite.h"

class Setup {

public:
    Setup(int screenWidth, int screenHeight);
    ~Setup();

    SDL_Renderer* getRenderer();
    SDL_Event* getEvent();

private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Event* event;
};

#endif // SETUP_H_INCLUDED
```

and this is the mainCharacter header:

```
#ifndef MAINCHARACTER_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINCHARACTER_H_INCLUDED

#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Setup.h"
#include <cmath>

class mainCharacter {

public:
    mainCharacter(Setup* pSetup, int* pMouseX, int* pMouseY);
    ~mainCharacter();

    double getDistance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

    void update();
    void draw();

private:
    Sprite* shagy;

    ///some variables are here/////

    Setup* setup;
};

#endif // MAINCHARACTER_H_INCLUDED
```

there are Setup.cpp and mainCharacter.cpp files and they got a long code written on them, the only thing i inclue in setup.cpp is setup.h and maincharacter.cpp i only include maincharacter.h

Comment: Well, given that you don't show us where `Setup` and `mainCharacter` are defined, we probably can't tell you.

Comment: Even though you are including `Setup.h` and `maincharacter.h` they may not have proper declarations for the types `Setup` and `maincharacter`. You'd have to make sure they are actually declared somewhere, possibly in those files.

Comment: Please provide Setup.h and/or mainCharacter.h.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef SETUP_H_INCLUDED
#define SETUP_H_INCLUDED
```

Make sure you aren't defining `SETUP_H_INCLUDED` somewhere else, this is the only reason i see.

Also it's possible that your %INCLUDE% (include directories) has another `Setup.h` somewhere, which does not define `Setup` class, and your `Setup.h` is not loaded.